# sum in mysql than group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a small lottery game for fun and to improve myself.
On the database, I have

```
table(id, package, value, price, purchase_code,round)
```

See an example. There is two package, package1 and package2.
package1 has a value of 3 and package2 has a value of 4. This means, that if I buy the package1, i got 3 ticket which is playing, giving me bigger chance to win in the current round, so it inserts 3 record into a table, containing the informations. So in this case, I have the following records in my table:

```
id     pacakage_id    value   price     purchase_code    round
1      1              3       10        w3hjkrw          1
2      1              3       10        w3hjkrw          1
3      1              3       10        w3hjkrw          1
```

I would like to see overall how money the users spent , and for this, I used sum(price).
Ok, but as you can see, the three record was one purchase, so sum(price) would give me the result 30. I tried to group by purchase_code, but it is not doing what I want.

Here is the code:

```
$income_query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(price) FROM lottery WHERE round = '$current_round' GROUP BY code") or die(mysql_error());
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($income_query)) {
$round_money = $result['SUM(price)']." $";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you will need to do a sub query to get the package id price. Possibly using distinct, although I would just use a normal aggregate function (MAX will do the job here).

Something like this:-

```
SELECT code, SUM(package_id_price)
FROM(
    SELECT code, package_id, MAX(price) AS package_id_price
    FROM lottery 
    WHERE round = '$current_round' 
    GROUP BY code, package_id
) Sub1
GROUP BY code
```

Comment: Thank You sir, I would never figure out by my own, but now I learned a lot :)